# Very basic table view but getting errors

Tags: iphone, uitableview

trying to write this code since 2 days now, but i keep getting error, it would be nice if anyone could sort this out, thanks.

Basically its the same thing i doing from the tutorial on youtube.

awaiting a reply

```
#import "BooksTableViewController.h"
#import "BooksDetailViewController.h"
#import "MYbooksAppDelegate.h"

@implementation BooksTableViewController
@synthesize BooksArray;
@synthesize BooksDetailViewController;

 - (void)viewDidLoad { 
 [super viewDidLoad];
 self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"XYZ",@"GOD is GREAT");

 NSMutableArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"H1",@"2",@"3",nil];
 self.booksArray = array;
 [array release];

}

#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.booksArray count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *identity = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identity];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:identity] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
 cell.textLabel.text = [booksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 return cell;
}

// ...various boiler plate methods
@end
```

Comment: (sigh…) What error do you get?

Comment: Nothing in the original or edited code looks wrong assuming that the garbled section was a pasting error. What error did you get? We're not psychic, you know.

Answer (score 0):

Besides you didn't give us the exact error you're trying to close there's at least one warning I would give :)

```
[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:identity]
```

This is deprecated code. You should rather use

```
[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identity]
```

if you're using OS 3.x (what I'm assuming).